# Android Gradle 2.0.1 issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm facing strange issue.

When I used the gradle plugin version 2.0.1 to create my android application, the very first installation taking too much time to open the application (App is running very quickly from next time on wards). And the app screen freezes in black screen for a while when the app just opens after installation.

This is my main gradle dependency block content

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

And my app gradle dependancy block is following

```
dependencies {
//  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `minSDKVersion` to 16 and change the gradle version to the latest.

Comment: My Minimum SDK version is 18

Comment: are you using gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: yes,it is gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

As  @janki gadhiya pointed. I found solution.

***Please disable the "instant run"***

To disable instant run Go to 
**File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run**